Will this SPI level shifting schematic work?
I have an IMU that is controlled through SPI from a MCU, however some slaves on the SPI bus are 5V logic but this IMU is 3V3 only, so I need to level shift.


A1 = CLK
A2 = MOSI
A3 = CS
A4 = MISO

The level shifter I used is the TXU0304PWR, which:

steps the CLK, MOSI and CS pins from 5V -> 3V3
steps MISO from 3V3 -> 5V

I invert the CS pin to ensure the level shifter OE pin is off when the MCU is communicating with other chips.
The IMU connection were based off the datasheet layout in figure 7 (page 21)

Counter question, woud it be simpler to run everything else at 3.3V too so you don't need two extra chips and a few pull resistors for level shifting?

Good point, I will check the datasheets to see if they accept 3V3. Thanks

The TXU0304 looks a good choice for level-shifting SPI, with 3 signals shifted from VCCA to VCCB and 1 signal shifted in the opposite direction.
Only issue I can is that when the TXU0304 outputs are disabled, the ICM-42688-P CS, SCLK and SDI inputs will be floating which could cause undefined behaviour. Suggest use a pull-up on the ICM-42688-P CS and SCLK to put them in a defined state when the TXU0304 outputs are disabled.
